# Google Places API library is not returning photo_reference attribute

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Places API to get the details of a place, but it's not returning the photo_reference attributes for the photos. Why??

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
  var request = {
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
  service.getDetails(request, callback);

  function callback(placeD, status) {
    console.log( placeD );
    console.log( JSON.stringify(placeD) );
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log( placeD );
    }
  }
```

And here's the response

```
{
   "address_components":[
      {
         "long_name":"5",
         "short_name":"5",
         "types":[
            "floor"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"48",
         "short_name":"48",
         "types":[
            "street_number"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"Pirrama Road",
         "short_name":"Pirrama Rd",
         "types":[
            "route"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"Pyrmont",
         "short_name":"Pyrmont",
         "types":[
            "locality",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"Council of the City of Sydney",
         "short_name":"Sydney",
         "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"New South Wales",
         "short_name":"NSW",
         "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"Australia",
         "short_name":"AU",
         "types":[
            "country",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "long_name":"2009",
         "short_name":"2009",
         "types":[
            "postal_code"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "adr_address":"5, <span class=\"street-address\">48 Pirrama Rd</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Pyrmont</span> <span class=\"region\">NSW</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">2009</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Australia</span>",
   "formatted_address":"5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
   "formatted_phone_number":"(02) 9374 4000",
   "geometry":{
      "location":{
         "lat":-33.8666113,
         "lng":151.19583239999997
      },
      "viewport":{
         "south":-33.8669293,
         "west":151.19521829999996,
         "north":-33.86650529999999,
         "east":151.1960371
      }
   },
   "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
   "id":"4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
   "international_phone_number":"+61 2 9374 4000",
   "name":"Google",
   "opening_hours":{
      "open_now":false,
      "periods":[
         {
            "close":{
               "day":1,
               "time":"1800",
               "hours":18,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1468828800000
            },
            "open":{
               "day":1,
               "time":"0800",
               "hours":8,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1468792800000
            }
         },
         {
            "close":{
               "day":2,
               "time":"1800",
               "hours":18,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1468915200000
            },
            "open":{
               "day":2,
               "time":"0800",
               "hours":8,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1468879200000
            }
         },
         {
            "close":{
               "day":3,
               "time":"1800",
               "hours":18,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1469001600000
            },
            "open":{
               "day":3,
               "time":"0800",
               "hours":8,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1468965600000
            }
         },
         {
            "close":{
               "day":4,
               "time":"1800",
               "hours":18,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1469088000000
            },
            "open":{
               "day":4,
               "time":"0800",
               "hours":8,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1469052000000
            }
         },
         {
            "close":{
               "day":5,
               "time":"1800",
               "hours":18,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1469174400000
            },
            "open":{
               "day":5,
               "time":"0800",
               "hours":8,
               "minutes":0,
               "nextDate":1469138400000
            }
         }
      ],
      "weekday_text":[
         "Monday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
         "Tuesday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
         "Wednesday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
         "Thursday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
         "Friday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
         "Saturday: Closed",
         "Sunday: Closed"
      ]
   },
   "photos":[
      {
         "height":1365,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105932078588305868215/photos\">Maksym Kozlenko</a>"
         ],
         "width":2048
      },
      {
         "height":3120,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116783625253584801301/photos\">Samson Jabin</a>"
         ],
         "width":4160
      },
      {
         "height":1184,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106645265231048995466/photos\">Malik Ahamed</a>"
         ],
         "width":1776
      },
      {
         "height":960,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100919424873665842845/photos\">Donnie Piercey</a>"
         ],
         "width":1280
      },
      {
         "height":3024,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117393076859685917096/photos\">Joann Chu</a>"
         ],
         "width":4032
      },
      {
         "height":5582,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110754641211532656340/photos\">Robert Koch</a>"
         ],
         "width":2866
      },
      {
         "height":2988,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103594026264127040754/photos\">Daniel Tyson</a>"
         ],
         "width":5312
      },
      {
         "height":2448,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116976377324210679577/photos\">WH CHEN</a>"
         ],
         "width":3264
      },
      {
         "height":1184,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106645265231048995466/photos\">Malik Ahamed</a>"
         ],
         "width":1776
      },
      {
         "height":4160,
         "html_attributions":[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116783625253584801301/photos\">Samson Jabin</a>"
         ],
         "width":3120
      }
   ],
   "place_id":"ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
   "rating":4.6,
   "reference":"CmRaAAAAXa9Pjme9u0GwglGBnp5nlj_r92tKtn3rY9mx22RTSHhZSNnYd3RvNVzl33PB_7qyhodZq_KkKx2KH9JIB0NYXuUNgVz2UKO_OMakrvJGVNrJ2Y6ue78-OVBtO6y5NdE0EhBCQrgjqWR2H2rv2ZWZrmPcGhT_f4ZFK2OYBor8uimEqGIwtBTfew",
   "reviews":[
      {
         "aspects":[
            {
               "rating":3,
               "type":"overall"
            }
         ],
         "author_name":"Nila Sweeney",
         "author_url":"https://plus.google.com/115167791509064907883",
         "language":"en",
         "profile_photo_url":"//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-P-5LDZmJbig/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAvAY/Df_n6XR0I2I/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "text":"Amazing place!  So incredibly vibrant and hip. I love the way the office have been laid out. The way work-life balance is encouraged is truly impressive!  Google, please hire me! ",
         "time":1464213084
      },
      {
         "aspects":[
            {
               "rating":0,
               "type":"overall"
            }
         ],
         "author_name":"TheHealthRetreat",
         "author_url":"https://plus.google.com/110246682709687277403",
         "language":"en",
         "rating":1,
         "text":"I spend 250 thousand dollars a year with Google adwords..\nI own a Mental Health Drug and alcohol retreat.\n\nA fictitious person Antony William posted a negative review on my Business.\n\nThis person has never attended.  I asked Google for the last 8 weeks to remove the third party review, I also sent 20 times a statutory declaration to googlemybusiness then goodle reviews and google legal stating Mr Antony had never attended the program.\n\nGoogle have refused to remove the review even though it clearly breaches Googles own guidelines and the post is defamatory.\nGoogle is enabling this person to continue to hurt our business by 100000 per month since the post went up.\n\nMy request for the post to be removed is being stone walled by google.\n\nI cannot believe that Google would treat their business partners so shabbily when they are being wronged by an anonymous person or I believe competition business.\nGoogle says over and over negotiate with Antony William,  how can I negotiate with someone who doesn't exist?  It is frustrating and plain wrong.\n\nIf Google does this to a client who spends 250000 ausd a year with them, god help us all.\n\nBy the way if you have depression and anxiety dealing with Google, come to us and we will help you. regards Francis",
         "time":1468373176
      },
      {
         "aspects":[
            {
               "rating":0,
               "type":"overall"
            }
         ],
         "author_name":"Steve Morgan",
         "author_url":"https://plus.google.com/103384372688674733198",
         "language":"en",
         "profile_photo_url":"//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-xCUbmlcbDas/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAIAE/OLWRkcph3xs/photo.jpg",
         "rating":1,
         "text":"Latest Andriod update 5.0 has broken Google  Play for the Samsung Note  3. No Gmail Apo no fitbit exercise  logging.  Absolutely  disgusting.  Almost sebds ne to Apple",
         "time":1468325696
      },
      {
         "aspects":[
            {
               "rating":3,
               "type":"overall"
            }
         ],
         "author_name":"Keith Hong",
         "author_url":"https://plus.google.com/106314339785578978358",
         "language":"en",
         "profile_photo_url":"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z69cMMxhr-c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEs/CbphM5oqKas/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "text":"Not often you get invited to the google Australia HQ. Neat spot. Love their Pirrama place but their ODI location is pretty cool too (and soon overtakin most of Fairfax) ",
         "time":1464676368
      },
      {
         "aspects":[
            {
               "rating":3,
               "type":"overall"
            }
         ],
         "author_name":"Alejandro Silva Avila",
         "author_url":"https://plus.google.com/102339092633102421576",
         "language":"en",
         "profile_photo_url":"//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WRvjv4eUHjY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAUsk/6UjJkZU6U9w/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "text":"Completely stunning and different from anything you'd imagine. So many cool things to see and do you'd think people get lost trying to do some work haha! :)",
         "time":1467896264
      }
   ],
   "scope":"GOOGLE",
   "types":[
      "point_of_interest",
      "establishment"
   ],
   "url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
   "utc_offset":600,
   "vicinity":"5 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
   "website":"https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/",
   "html_attributions":[

   ]
}
```

I can get the photo_reference attributes if I use this URL to see the details of the same place:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRaAAAAXa9Pjme9u0GwglGBnp5nlj_r92tKtn3rY9mx22RTSHhZSNnYd3RvNVzl33PB_7qyhodZq_KkKx2KH9JIB0NYXuUNgVz2UKO_OMakrvJGVNrJ2Y6ue78-OVBtO6y5NdE0EhBCQrgjqWR2H2rv2ZWZrmPcGhT_f4ZFK2OYBor8uimEqGIwtBTfew&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAmUTQw6a8sQESv77boQhf3tvTsaAJy09c
```

Comment: Funny seeing my name in code sample :-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

When using the javscript library, the photo objects have a method "getUrl" instead of a photo_reference. It's a bit confusing, but you can loop over those images and call that method with a maxHeight and/or a maxWidth (at least one of them must be present) and it will return a photo url.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacePhoto

```
function callback(placeD, status) {
    console.log( placeD );
    console.log( JSON.stringify(placeD) );
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        placeD.photos.forEach(photo => {
            console.log(photo.getUrl({maxHeight: 300})) // will log a url but no photo_reference
        })
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately I have not yet figured out how to get a photo_reference from the javascript library.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Negative, had to stick with the method I described above. It's a shame you can't just get the reference. Or maybe there is a way now, I haven't poked around recently.

Answer (score -3):

You need to get the photo reference from the `Place Search` or `Place Details` request.

The [Place Photo service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos), part of the Google Places API Web Service, is a read-only API that allows you to add high quality photographic content to your application.

When you get place information using a Place Details request, photo references will be returned for relevant photographic content.

All requests to the Place Photo service must include a `photoreference`. It is a string identifier that uniquely identifies a photo. Photo references are returned from either a Place Search or Place Details request.

An example of a `photos[]` array is shown below.

```
...

"photos" : [
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"height" : 853,
"width" : 1280,
"photo_reference" : "CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0"
}
...
```

A Place Photo request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters

Comment: My question is specifically about retrieving the photo_reference, not what to do once I have it. I am using a Place Details request, right? -- service.getDetails

Comment: This doesnt answers the question sorry